# How to insert one array into another where only zeros are (with Numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices in NumPy. One is larger than the other. I want to insert the smaller 2D-array (randomly) into the bigger 2D-array where there are only zeros (so no actual information in the bigger one is lost). Example:

Big array:

```
[0 0 0 9] 
[0 0 0 7]
[0 0 0 2]
[2 3 1 5]
```

Small array:

```
[3 3]
[3 3]
```

(Possible) result:

```
[3 3 0 9] 
[3 3 0 7]
[0 0 0 2]
[2 3 1 5]
```

Comment: do you want to insert the smaller array and preserve its shape in the big array? or randomly choose 0 entries in the big array and fill it with a random entry from the small array? you need to be more specific

Comment: It's suppossed to retain its shape, yes. Sorry, I thought the example would clarify this.

Comment: The first non-trivial task is to find possible slots.  For a start I'd write a small function that tests whether an (i,j) index is a possible slot.  Then iterate on all pairs, collecting the possibles.  Finally select one randomly. Actually not so difficult if you take small steps at a time.

Comment: So there is no built-in way to say: "place in A, where values are 0"?

Comment: Is the larger array of an unsigned type?

Comment: @hpaulj I would have thought a person of your skills could use some *"stride tricks"* to sum the pixels of each rectangle the same size as the filler array and where they sum to zero the filler array will fit...

Comment: @Mark, I don't automatically think in terms of striding tricks. But now that you mention it, I picture using it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you! That is actually a great plan! I think I will do this!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use 2D convolution to find the places where the small array `b` can go in the large array `a`. If you use `scipy.signal.convolve2d` with `mode='valid'` you only get locations where the small array 'fits'. I think using the `abs` of the arays gets around positive and negative values (in either array) canceling, but I haven't tested any of this very rigorously.

Here's what I did, using @CypherX's `fill_a_with_b` function for the fill step:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal

# Your input data.
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 9], 
              [0, 0, 0, 7],
              [0, 0, 0, 2],
              [2, 3, 1, 5]])
b = np.ones((2, 2)) * 3

# Find places where b can go.
allowed = scipy.signal.convolve2d(np.abs(a), np.abs(b), mode='valid')

# Get these locations as (row, col) pairs.
coords = np.stack(np.where(allowed==0)).T

# Choose one of the locations at random.
choice = coords[np.random.randint(coords.shape[0])]

# Use @CypherX's 'fill' function.
def fill_a_with_b(a, b, pos=[0, 0]):
    aa = a.copy()
    aa[slice(pos[0], pos[0] + b.shape[0]), 
       slice(pos[1], pos[1] + b.shape[1])] = b.copy()
    return aa

# Do the fill thing.
fill_a_with_b(a, b, choice)
```

This results in (for example)...

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 3, 3, 7],
       [0, 3, 3, 2],
       [2, 3, 1, 5]])
```

Comment: Wow, this looks like a lot less than what I was going to write. I have a lot to learn, but your submission is very helpful, thank you very much! I have never worked with scipy before, but I'll give it a try! :)

Answer (score 1):

I will try giving you an example. But it will be based on some assumptions:

1. You know that the 0's are spanned across a contiguous rectangular block.
2. There are no other zeros in `a`.

If you would like to fill in a non-contiguous block of zeroes or, there are zeros on the columns/rows where you have some other non-zero values, you would have to think of a more sophisticated solution.

## Solution: Random Insertion of array `b` into array `a` where `a==0`

Assumption: we know that the places where `a` is zero are a contiguous set of positions with a rectangular shape.

### Imports

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg' # 'svg', 'retina'
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
```

### Make Data

```py
# Make a
shape = (5,5)
a = np.zeros(shape)
a[:,-1] = np.arange(shape[0]) + 10
a[-1,:] = np.arange(shape[1]) + 10
# Make b
b = np.ones((2,2))*2
```

### Preprocess

Here we determine possible slot-positions of the top-left element of `b` on `a`.

```py
# Get range of positions (rows and cols) where we have zeros
target_indices = np.argwhere(a==0)
minmax = np.array([target_indices.min(axis=0), target_indices.max(axis=0)])
# Define max position (index) of topleft element of b on a
maxpos = np.dot(np.array([-1,1]), minmax) + minmax[0,:] - (np.array(b.shape) -1)
# Define min position (index) of topleft element of b on a
minpos = minmax[0,:]
```

### Make a list of *Top Left Corner* Positions of `b` on `a`

Th function `get_rand_topleftpos()` takes in `minpos` and `maxpos` for rows and columns on `a` that define possible slot-positions, and returns a **randomly selected valid slot-position** for `size=1`. I have used a `size=20` to create quite a few valid random slot-positions and then select only the unique positions so we could then see them as images. If you need just one slot-position at a time, select `size=1`.

```py
def get_rand_topleftpos(minpos, maxpos, size=1):
    rowpos = np.random.randint(minpos[0], high=maxpos[0] + 1, size=size)
    colpos = np.random.randint(minpos[1], high=maxpos[1] + 1, size=size)
    pos = np.vstack([rowpos, colpos]).T
    return (rowpos, colpos, pos)

# Make a few valid positions where the array b could be placed
rowpos, colpos, pos = get_rand_topleftpos(minpos, maxpos, size=20)
# Select the Unique combinations so we could visualize them only
pos = np.unique(pos, axis=0)
```

### Place `b` on `a` and Make Figures

We make a custom defined function `fill_a_with_b()` to fill `a` with `b` at a certain postion on `a`. This position will accept the top-left cell of `b`.

```py
def fill_a_with_b(a, b, pos = [0,0]):
    aa = a.copy()
    aa[slice(pos[0], pos[0] + b.shape[0]), 
       slice(pos[1], pos[1] + b.shape[1])] = b.copy()
    return aa

# Make a few figures with randomly picked position 
# for topleft position of b on a

if pos.shape[0]>6:
    nrows, ncols = int(np.ceil(pos.shape[0]/6)), 6
else:
    nrows, ncols = 1, pos.shape[0]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = nrows, 
                        ncols = ncols, 
                        figsize=(2.5*ncols,2.5*nrows))
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flatten()):    
    if i<pos.shape[0]:
        aa = fill_a_with_b(a, b, pos[i,:]) 

        sns.heatmap(aa, 
                    vmin=np.min(aa), 
                    vmax=np.max(aa), 
                    annot=True, 
                    cbar=False,
                    square=True,
                    cmap = 'YlGnBu_r', 
                    ax = ax
                   ); 

        ax.set_title('TopLeftPos: {}'.format(tuple(pos[i,:])), 
                     fontsize=9);
    else:
        ax.axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()        
plt.show()
```

### Results

#### With array `a` defined as:

```py
shape = (5,5)
a = np.zeros(shape)
a[:,-1] = np.arange(shape[0]) + 10
a[-1,:] = np.arange(shape[1]) + 10
```

[image]

#### With array `a` defined as:

```py
shape = (6,5)
a = np.zeros(shape)
a[:,0] = np.arange(shape[0]) + 10
a[:,-1] = np.arange(shape[0]) + 10
a[-1,:] = np.arange(shape[1]) + 10
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Your submission has been incredibly helpful and I actually learned quite a lot from it!